# enabling ESM / Ubuntu Pro in Pop! OS

Tags: pop-os

I am currently using Pop OS 22.04, and I know that this version of Pop rests on top of Ubuntu.

I wanted to ask if there will be issues if I activated Ubuntu Pro and enabled ESM software/infra updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how true your statement about pop OS is. I'll assume you've done research at the documentation of pop OS to verify it, and take the statement as fact.

There's really no telling. By the time you use Ubuntu's extended long-term support, whatever is built on top won't be supported, as far as I can tell. So, the question here really becomes what you'd *gain* here; after all, any update that you gain in the future through esm might break your system then, because how should Ubuntu know it care what another team of developers sculpted atop of it?

Honestly, your best course of action is choosing a distro who's *own* support policy fits your needs. And assuming you're thinking about this because you don't want the hassle of updating your desktop distro in a few years, I'd recommend you either get over that, or just switch to Ubuntu LTS, Debian LTS, or Alma Linux, if Pop OS is too aggressive when it comes to updates.

Comment: The current Pop! OS is based on Ubuntu LTS 22.04 (they're numbered the same way), but it is supported only until 2027. You are absolutely correct that I want to limit the hassle of updating. I guess this will be a case study to see if ESM breaks the OS after 2027.